# Get "invalid-sender" error in Mandrill when try to send template

Tags: php, codeigniter, mandrill

I have 4 templates but one returns error: `"reject_reason": "invalid-sender"`.

I didn't find this error. in Docs.

I have 4 templates in my account and current template has following structure:

- Template Slug: `contact-home`
- From Address : `info@somecomp.com`
- From Name:     `SOME_COMP`

++ template as HTML.

This is a request I send from API Logs:

**Full Request**

```
{
    "template_name": "contact-home",
    "template_content": [
        {
            "name": "example name",
            "content": "example content"
        }
    ],
    "message": {
        "dest_mail": "mymail@gmail.com",
        "merge": "true",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "mymail@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "merge_vars": [
            {
                "rcpt": "mymail@gmail.com",
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "FNAME",
                        "content": "name"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

**Full response**

```
[
    {
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "status": "rejected",
        "_id": "a305475c544a4f12a52f5a2b205c2505",
        "reject_reason": "invalid-sender"
    }
]
```

I don't think its PHP problem because 3 other templates have the same structure and I use one PHP method.

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think its Mandrill issue.

The fix is:

1. open template
2. remove sender mail
3. press Publish
4. set the same mail
5. press Publish

Now its work.

If you need additional info let me know

Thanks