# How to get mail list that mandrill failed to sent to?

Tags: mandrill

We found that some clients didn't get mail because of followed issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237899/get-invalid-sender-error-in-mandrill-when-try-to-send-template)

How can we get all mails that failed to get mail?

Does Mandrill provide any API?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mandrill does have a robust API, and you can easily retrieve the list of emails that have failed.

See Mandrill's API documentation here: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/rejects.JSON.html#method=list

They have examples in a bunch of popular languages, and you can even test the responses with your real API key on that same documentation page!