# Mail is getting rejected when sent using Mandrill API

Tags: php, api, email, mandrill

I am trying to send email using Mandrill API, but I am getting response as below:

`{
"email":"_emailid_",
"status":"rejected",
"_id":"967859c539b1416abc2613b5a3619a46",
"reject_reason":"invalid-sender"
}`

I am sending the mail by hitting curl call on mandrill api like [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html).

Can somebody tell me what might be reason for the rejection ?

Comment: What does your API call look like (you should obfuscate your API key, of course)? You may also want to view http://stackoverflow.com/a/20238127/899126

Comment: First I am creating the mandrill objects and then I am sending the mail via message/send.

Comment: We'd need to know with more specificity the entire API call that you're making, with details obfuscated. That error typically means that you're not providing the `from_email` parameter as expected, so a valid sender address hasn't been provided.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a long time this question was posted, but I guess I still can contribute.

I had the same issue this week when using MailChimp Transactional API calling a POST method through the command
curl -X POST 
https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template 
-d '{"key":"","template_name":"","template_content":[],"message": etc... }

and I got the error message :

[{"email":"some_name@gmail.com.br","status":"rejected","_id":"2bff316436814a399fafea22fda4a4dd","reject_reason":"recipient-domain-mismatch"}]

Asking MailChimp's support team about this, they reply , after a couple of days, the following :

*The recipient domain mismatch reject reason is specific to demo and trial accounts and refers to a limitation in those accounts. Sending is restricted to the domains you have set up in the account already. This means your recipient would need to be on a domain that you have the same setup as mentioned for your sending address. If you change to a paid account, this restriction would be removed automatically and you could send to any recipients. Plainly put, you can only send to domains you have verified/authenticated on the demo mode.*

I use a free account.  I search the documentation and several other sources in the internet but I found no reference to this free account limitation.
It would be very productive if such limitation was explicitly put.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that your API key is fine. The bad news is that you probably need to [configure the email sender domain](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582247) so that mandrill knows the sender is valid.